# Passing a variable from php to javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Hi I am trying to pass a variable on button click from a php function to javascript. The output is undefined for some reason but at the php function the variable does contain data. Any idea why this is happening?

PHP:

```
    add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'create_pdf_row_actions', 10, 2 );
function create_pdf_row_actions( $actions, WP_Post $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type != 'item' ) {
        return $actions;
    }

   # $actions['create-pdf'] = "<a href='#?id=".$post->ID."'  >Create PDF</a>";
    $actions['create-pdf'] = "<a href='#?id=".$post->ID."'  >Create PDF".$post->ID."</a>";
    return $actions;
}
```

Javascript:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.create-pdf').on('click', function () {
        alert("button"+ $(this).data("id"));
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: What does the PHP code in your question have to do with the JS code? Were you supposed to have an element with `class="create-pdf"` somewhere?

Comment: Yes the php hook automatically wraps the a tag in a script tag with class="create-pdf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) accesses an element's [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) but the `id` in your link appears to be in the URL fragment of the `href` attribute.

You have two options...

1. Add the appropriate `data-id` attribute to your link

   ```php
   $actions['create-pdf'] = sprintf(
       '<a href="#?id=%1$s" data-id="%1$s">Create PDF%1$s</a>',
       htmlspecialchars($post->ID)
   );
   ```

   ```js
   $(".create-pdf").on("click", "a[data-id]", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert(`button${$(this).data("id")}`);
   });
   ```
2. Or, extract the `id` from the params in the URL fragment

   ```js
   $(".create-pdf").on("click", "a[href]", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     const url = new URL(this.href);
     const params = new URLSearchParams(url.hash.slice(1));
     alert(`button${params.get("id")}`);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from the piece of code,
You can try:

Calling the PHP function within jQuery by using the `<?php ?>` tags. Since `$actions['create-pdf']` is inside an array, use `print_r` to output the variable, or use `foreach loop` if you have multipile key-value pairs

Comment: <?php create_pdf_row_actions ?> do you mean something like this?

Comment: if create_pdf_row_actions is an array then use `<?php print_r($create_pdf_row_actions); ?>` or a variable, then `<?php  echo $create_pdf_row_actions ;?>`